# When was the 10,000 B limit for scripts introduced?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, transaction-verification, consensus

The file `src/script/script.h` defines a `MAX_SCRIPT_SIZE` of 10,000 B. Among other instances, the `MAX_SCRIPT_SIZE` is used in the `IsUnspendable()` check, which allows us to avoid adding outputs with excessively long `scriptPubKeys` to the UTXO set. It also causes input validation to fail if a `scriptSig` exceeds the permitted length.

[image: A code snippet from the Bitcoin Core code base showing the use of MAX_SCRIPT_SIZE in IsUnspendable()]

In the context of talking about this limit, I was asked and didn't know: "When was the `MAX_SCRIPT_SIZE` introduced?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was introduced in v0.3.7, dated July 31 2010, in commit [73aa262647](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/73aa262647ff9948eaf95e83236ec323347e95d0), titled "fixed segfault in bignum.h, additional security limits, refactoring -- version 0.3.7":

```
     vector<valtype> altstack;
-    if (pvStackRet)
-        pvStackRet->clear();
-    if (script.size() > 20000)
+    if (script.size() > 10000)
         return false;
+    int nOpCount = 0;
```

It apparently replaced an older 20000-byte limit (TIL!), which was introduced in v0.3.6, dated a day earlier, in commit [a75560d828](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/a75560d828464c3f1138f52cf247e956fc8f937d), titled "reverted makefile.unix wx-config -- version 0.3.6":

```
     if (pvStackRet)
         pvStackRet->clear();
+    if (script.size() > 20000)
+        return false;
```

Comment: the second link has a typo and doesn't work.

Comment: @bordalix Thanks, fixed!